# Arduino Светодиод горит когда число четное

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Если я отправляю в порт число больше десяти, светодиод должен загораться, но он загорается когда число четное. И судя по всему я где-то просто туплю.

```
int ledPin = 13;

void setup(){
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
  
void loop (){
  Serial.read();
  if (Serial.read() > 10){
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
  else{}
}
```

[image: Схема подключения(транзистор на 220 ом)]

Comment: Вероятнее всего, проблема в перепутанных параметрах порта - скорости, разрядности, четности и так далее.

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/readstring/ https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/toint/ https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/available/

Comment: тут же сравнивается второй байт на входе, а не первый

Answer (score 1):

```
void loop (){
    if (Serial.available()) {
        if (Serial.read() > 10) {
           digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
           delay(1000);
           digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
        }
    }
}
```

Имейте в виду, что если вы отправляете данные через Монитор порта Arduino IDE, отправляя строку "10\r\n", то читать данные нужно иначе:

```
void loop() {
   int n = read_int();
   if (n > 10) {
       ... // код светодиода
   }
}
int read_int() {
   int n = 0;
   while (true) {
       while (Serial.available() == 0) {}
       char ch = Serial.read();
       if (ch == '\n')
          return n;
       if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
          n = n * 10 + ch - '0';
   }
}
```